# DataVisualization Sprite doesn't show in iPad

Tags: autodesk-forge

My product that was built on Forge & DataVisualizationAPI stopped showing sprites a few weeks ago (it was working fine earlier). I checked the Dasher 360 demo, and it behaves the same way (works in my computer but not in iPad or Xcode simulator). Not specific to Safari but Chrome behaves the same way.

Browser console doesn't show any (related) error either.

If anyone knows what has changed during past few weeks, or some workaround, please let me know.

Thanks,
Bandu

[image: macOS on the left, iPad on the right]
[image: Browser inspector - Console]

Comment: Which Viewer version are you using? And as you mentioned iPad, can you please confirm iOS and Safari version?

Comment: Viewer version 7.69
iOS/Safari version 15.4.1
iOS Chrome version 101.0.4951.58

Comment: These three errors are fine to ignore. They are for the source map file of the minified javascript file used for debugging propose. On production env, they will be removed. Could you help keep opening the dev console, reload the web page, and find if there is any other error or warning messages?

Comment: @EasonKang, no other errors in the console.

Comment: @BanduW could you help test with v7.64? Change your viewer references like the below

Comment: <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.64/viewer3D.js"></script>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.64/style.css">

Comment: @EasonKang, you are a lifesaver! v7.64 fixed it . Is it production ready for me to use it?

Comment: @BanduW Thank you for your kind confirmation. Yes, v7.64 is a production-ready version. The latest production version is v7.69. I will report this to our engineering team for futher investigation.

Comment: @EasonKang is there any other way to target the objects inside of cad. need to know sir. Like in doc i saw you pass the x,y,z position. easier way out of that would be to access object using the object name,id .How to do that thing.,and if that is not possible please tell how to make it happend or how to find the x,y,z position of an object in javascript

Comment: @EasonKang Also there is an alert coming up everytime i reload, saying the api is in development and not tested fully

Comment: @EasonKang We are a startup builiding things for the future.

Comment: @AdarshRaj it's fixed in v7.71. Could you have a try? https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#section-6

Comment: how do you find the position of a component using the api in react?  need to display a sprite over it. @EasonKang

Comment: No need to focus on the react or no react. Viewer API is written in JavaScript. Once you have viewer instance, you should be able to use its functions in react. Commonly, I get object position via its bounding box center. https://github.com/yiskang/forge-bim360-assets.viewer/blob/bim360-iot-connected/bim360assets/wwwroot/js/BIM360IotConnectedExtension.js#L1402

Comment: Or use hitTest to get intersect point on the mesh: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/blob/e316d48dabe8b25f1fe28fe9595177c9c6efb75e/client/pages/extensions/SensorManagerExtension.js#L317 It's under [this PR](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/pull/12)